# Give an example to show that in general $h(P)$ is not an ideal of $S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

**Let $h: R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $P\subset R$ be a prime ideal.**
**Give an example to show that in general $h(P)$ is not an ideal of $S$**

The first thing I think is to take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $P=(2)$ but I do not know how to take $S$ or if this works in this way, any help is appreciated.

*Note:* $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings with unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $S=\mathbb{R}$. With the injection map $h(x)=x$, $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and any prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, say $P=(2)$ as you suggested.

Comment: And how do we take $R$? What is the prime ideal that fails to be sent to an ideal?

Comment: @user402543 we take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $P=(2)$ as you suggested in your question. Edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can consider $R=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $S=\mathbb{C}$ and $h:R \to S$ as in $h(p)=p(1)$.

You can see that $<x>$ is prime in $R$. And $h(R)=\mathbb{R}$, which is not an ideal in $\mathbb{C}$.